# Randomizing order of test execution with nosetests

Tags: python, nose

I have a suite of tests that I recently discovered had an (incorrect) ordering relationship. They are all supposed to be independent.

Nose appears to run tests in the same order each time, which will not per se uncover these dependencies unless the *magic* happens and I manage to inject something which causes a failure (not my favorite method of programming).

How do I instruct nose to randomize the order of tests it executes?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to do this. I looked around, and there's this nose plugin that purports to randomize test order:

https://github.com/my8bird/nose-randomize

From the source, it looks like it only works for tests that inherit from unittest.TestCase. If that doesn't work for you, you could certainly use it as a start for writing your own.

If you just want a one-off to expose dependancies, you can pass a list of tests to nose. A lazyass method would be to get the list of your tests, and pass all permutations one by one:

```
nosetests /path/to/testA.py /path/to/testB.py /path/to/testC.py
nosetests /path/to/testA.py /path/to/testC.py /path/to/testB.py
nosetests /path/to/testB.py /path/to/testA.py /path/to/testC.py
nosetests /path/to/testB.py /path/to/testC.py /path/to/testA.py
nosetests /path/to/testC.py /path/to/testA.py /path/to/testB.py
nosetests /path/to/testC.py /path/to/testB.py /path/to/testA.py
```

It might take all night to run, but you'd at least know where your problems are.

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: It's probably better to do it this way, anyway.  If you **do** find test order dependencies, it is going to be very difficult to sort them out if the order is different each time.

I'd also recommend checking out the --with-id option; it might be simpler to permute by test IDs than by full test descriptors (path:class:method).

Comment: I think [this plugin](https://github.com/nloadholtes/nose-randomize) is a bit better -- it lets you set a seed and will also tell you what seed is used for each run

Answer (score -1):

you can run then in order by specifying the fully qualifed path of testcase with class name

```
./nose <<testcasename>>:<<classname>>.testcase_name1 <<testcasename>>:<<classname>>.testcase_name2
        <<testcasename>>:<<classname>>.testcase_name4
```

copy these path in bat.cfg file and run with ./nose -c bat.cfg